# PHP: categorizing characters in a string

Tags: php, regex, string

Consider the following string

*hello, my name is 冰岛, nice to meet you*

I need to scan this string and categorize each character as one of the following types:

- 1) Western text  (alphabet and numbers only)
- 2) Chinese text (ideograms only, no punctuation)
- 3) Anything else (anything else,    whether western or chinese or else)

Anyone can point me in the right direction? Thanks

Edit: since I suppose this has been downvoted due to being too generic..

```
for($i=0, $l = mb_strlen($string) - 1; $i<$l; $i++)
  {
   $char = mb_substr($string, $i, 1);

   if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/", $char)) $type = "alpha";
   else
   ...
   ;
  }
```

Regular expressions other than detecting alphabetic characters defy my knowledge, especially what is needed to include Han Ideograms only and leave all Han punctuation and special symbols out.

Comment: What is the output you need? Also, by Western, do you mean only ASCII letters, or extended ones like `ą`?

Comment: Good point: yes, extended, not just ASCII. I am trying to do my own research to solve this problem, but I am a newbie at character sets and regular expressions, and lacking the correct terminology is a big obstacle. As for the final output, it's tricky. I need to break sentences in blocks, with each block belonging to one of those 3 categories. So for example [{text:"Hi", type:"western"}, {text:",", type:"punctuation"}, {text:"my", type:"western"}, {text:"name", type:"western"}, {text:"is", type:"western"}, {text:"小熊", type:"han"}]

Comment: I posted an answer that can help you tokenize *words* out of the string. It might not be a 100% solution, but it shows the way you seem to want.

Comment: Well, there *are* language classifier/identifier libraries out there, which are a little more involved than a regex. How properly do you want to do this…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest that you should use a `preg_replace_callback` to grab the chunks of text you need with a regex that will capture different categories of texts into separate groups, and build the resulting array based on these captures:

```
$s = "hello, my name is 冰岛, nice to meet you";
$res = array();
preg_replace_callback('~\b(?<Chinese>\p{Han}+)\b|\b(?<Western>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b|(?<Other>[^\p{Han}A-Za-z0-9\s]+)~su',
 function($m) use (&$res) {
    if (!empty($m["Chinese"])) {
        $t = array("type" => "Han", "value" => $m["Chinese"]);
        array_push($res,$t);
    }
    else if (!empty($m["Western"])) {
        $t = array("type" => "Western", "value" => $m["Western"]);
        array_push($res, $t);
    }
    else  if (!empty($m["Other"])) {
        $t=array("type" => "Other", "value" => $m["Other"]);
        array_push($res, $t);
    }
 },
$s);
print_r($res);
```

See the [online PHP demo](https://ideone.com/VnEU9D)

**Pattern**:

- `\b(?<Chinese>\p{Han}+)\b` - a whole Chinese word
- `|` - or
- `\b(?<Western>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b` - a whole word consisting of only ASCII letters and digits
- `|` - or
- `(?<Other>[^\p{Han}A-Za-z0-9\s]+)` - any 1+ symbols other than Chinese chars, ASCII letters, ASCII digits and whitespaces (`\s`).

The `~s` modifier is redundant here, but if you want to match linebreaks, it will make `.` match these chars.

The `~u` is necessary here since you deal with Unicode strings.

Also, see more about Unicode properties in the [***Unicode Properties*** section at the regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) (e.g. you might be interested in `\p{P}` and `\p{S}` properties).

Comment: Thanks. Very comprehensive and easy to further generalize. Works perfectly.